# stop object timeline from looping

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movie with several movieClips. One of the movieClips has a timeline with a motion tween. I created an instance of this movieClip:

```
var board:Board = new Board();
```

and used `board.gotoAndStop(1);`  to keep the movieClip from playing at the beginning of the movie.

An eventListener checks to see when board collides with something; when it does, a function is invoked that uses `board.gotoAndPlay(2)` to get the board's timeline going.

I want the playhead on that timeline to stop at the end of the action, rather than looping. I tried to put a `stop()` on the last frame of that timeline, but Flash tells me I can't put an action on an object.

Can you help me solve this?

Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, you need to make sure you have clicked in the frame in the timeline, so the frame is selected, and not an object on the stage. Then enter your actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select a single frame where you would like to add actions then add your code

```
stop();
```

To make the timeline stop looping